# Lest + it + subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctives

As far as I know, "lest" should always be used with subjunctive mood, yet I find the following sentence quite unnatural, though it satisfies the rule:

> We should publish a critique on this method, lest **it gain** momentum.

Is this example correct? Personally, I find it very hard to read the sentence without automatically replacing "gain" with "gains". I've found a similar [example](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lest) with "anyone", which makes me think that my intuition fails me:

> "Lest anyone forget, adolescence is purgatory" (Jon Pareles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style of you example is elevated, but correct. Using "lest" is not normally done in plain English. It gives a slightly "showing off" style to the language. I would not recommend language learners use "lest", except in fixed expressions.

In plain English you could say

> ... or else it might gain momentum.

Answer (score 2):

> *We should publish a critique on this method, lest it gain momentum*.

The subjunctive is the preferred construction in adversatives. But specialised "should" is also readily used: *lest it should gain momentum*. And it's even possible, though much rarer, to find an ordinary declarative: *lest it gains momentum.*

Whichever construction is used, "lest" belongs to formal style, and its use is comparatively rare nowadays.